Show the subtitle in the Montpellier theme headline instead of the title
I'm working on a beamer presentation using the Montpellier theme, and the first info it shows in the headline is the title, but i would like to show the subtitle instead.
I've seen that one possible option would be to change the beamerouterthemetree.sty file, but is it possible to change that in the main.tex file?
\documentclass{beamer}
%Information to be included in the title page:

\usetheme{Montpellier}
\title{Sample title}
\subtitle{This is the subtitle}
\author{Anonymous}
\institute{Overleaf}
\date{2021}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}
This is some text in the first frame. This is some text in the first frame. This is some text in the first frame.
\end{frame}

\end{document}



The headline actually shows the short title, so you could use the optional argument of \title to set it to whatever you want:
\documentclass{beamer}
%Information to be included in the title page:

\usetheme{Montpellier}
\title[This is the subtitle]{Sample title}
\subtitle{This is the subtitle}
\author{Anonymous}
\institute{Overleaf}
\date{2021}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}
This is some text in the first frame. This is some text in the first frame. This is some text in the first frame.
\end{frame}

\end{document}


